# Converting .txt file to CSV using DOS Batch

Tags: command-prompt

Can anyone help me with code.
I want convert .txt file to csv using dos batch. I have created a bat file with below code but its not working.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
```

`rem Define` constants here:

```
set "INPUT=C:\New folde(2)\XYZ.txt"
set "OUTPUT=C:\New folder (2)\"

if not defined INPUT exit /B 1
if not defined OUTPUT set "OUTPUT=con"

> "%OUTPUT%" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%INPUT%") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINE:^|^|=,!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

but this is not working. can anyone please help me with the exact code to convert `txt` file to `csv` using cmd prompt?
appreciate your help!

Comment: code used to achieve the task is below: 






@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "INPUT=%~1"
set "OUTPUT=%~2"

if not defined INPUT exit /B 1
if not defined OUTPUT set "OUTPUT=con"
> "%OUTPUT%" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%INPUT%") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINE:^|^|=,!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B

Answer (score 0):

**1st**: the variable `OUTPUT` should point to a *file*, e.g. as follows:

<strike>`set "OUTPUT=C:\New folder (2)\"`</strike>
`set "OUTPUT=C:\New folder (2)\XYZ.csv"`

**2nd**: supposing that you need to replace vertical lines with commas:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Define constants here:

set "INPUT=%~1"
set "OUTPUT=%~2"

if not defined INPUT (
    set "INPUT=D:\bat\SO\62897755.txt" 
) else (
    if not defined OUTPUT set "OUTPUT=%~dpn1.csv" 
)
if not defined OUTPUT set "OUTPUT=con:"

echo Converting "%INPUT%" to "%OUTPUT%"

>"%OUTPUT%" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%INPUT%") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set "LINE=!LINE:|=,!"
            echo(!LINE!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

**Initial input and output files:**

```
type "D:\bat\SO\62897755.txt"
```

> ```
> name|no|columnAa|columnBb
> abc1|11|columnA1|columnB!
> def2|22|columnA2|columnB2
> ghi3|33|columnA3|columnB3
> ```

```
type "D:\bat\SO\62897755.csv"
```

> ```
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

**Usage samples:**

```
D:\bat\SO\62897755.bat
```

> ```
> Converting "D:\bat\SO\62897755.txt" to "con:"
> name,no,columnAa,columnBb
> abc1,11,columnA1,columnB!
> def2,22,columnA2,columnB2
> ghi3,33,columnA3,columnB3
> ```

```
D:\bat\SO\62897755.bat "D:\bat\SO\62897755.txt" con
```

> ```
> Converting "D:\bat\SO\62897755.txt" to "con"
> name,no,columnAa,columnBb
> abc1,11,columnA1,columnB!
> def2,22,columnA2,columnB2
> ghi3,33,columnA3,columnB3
> ```

```
D:\bat\SO\62897755.bat ".\SO\62897755.txt"
```

> ```
> Converting ".\SO\62897755.txt" to "d:\bat\SO\62897755.csv"
> ```

```
type "D:\bat\SO\62897755.csv"
```

> ```
> name,no,columnAa,columnBb
> abc1,11,columnA1,columnB!
> def2,22,columnA2,columnB2
> ghi3,33,columnA3,columnB3
> ```

Comment: where is the code for input file. I mean where it is taking input text file and and under which path it is creating the ouput. Do I need to mention output file name or it will auto created. I tried but its not working.

Basically I want -- I have a txt file with Pipe delimited and I want to convert it into csv using dos batch.

Comment: @PremYadav  answer updated, see the script as well as usage samples…